# Can bwameth accept unaligned Bam?

Tags: sam, bwa, methylation

Does [bwameth](https://github.com/brentp/bwa-meth) accept `bam` (unaligned) type as input or I will have to convert unaligned bam to fastq (`samtools fastq bam`) to use it as input?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it's a bwa mem wrapper for bisulfite data essentially and bwa mem accepts fastq only.

Comment: You can pipe uBAM to bwamem with `samtools fastq in.bam | bwa mem -p - > out.sam`, provided that paired-end reads are grouped by name.